# Issues on editing nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `simple_form`, a known Rails gem that makes the forms a little bit easier. I am having trouble to edit the forms. I can save the records perfectly, but when I go to the `edit` action, I don't see the records of the nested object from the database.

## Models

```
# app/models/user.rb
has_one :member
has_one :academic, through: :member

accepts_nested_attributes_for :member, reject_if: :all_blank 

# app/models/member.rb
belongs_to :user

has_one academic, dependent: :delete
accepts_nested_attributes_for academic, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

# app/models/academic.rb
belongs_to :member
```

## Controller

```
# app/controllers/member_controller.rb

def edit
 @member = Member.find(params[:id])
 @academic = Academic.find_by_member_id(params[:id])

 @member.build_academic
 @member.academic.build_exchange_student # ExchangeStudent belongs_to :academic also
end
```

## View

```
# app/views/_form.html.erb partial on app/views/edit.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @member, url: database_members_path do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :academic do |academic_exchange_student| %>
  <%= academic_exchange_student.fields_for :exchange_student do |exchange| %>

<!-- ##### Exchange student -->
  <div class="row">
      <%= academic_exchange_student.text_field :major%>
  </div>

<% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Yes, I am permitting the `ids` in the `params.require(...)`. The record is saved perfectly, I can see it in the `rails console`.

When I go to this `edit` page, I can see the information of the member already in the `text_field`, but I don't see the information of the `@member.academic.major` there.

Also, if I go to the edit page and return in the browser, the `academic` record is deleted mysteriously.

**Any help will be appreciated**. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem here is that you build a new `academic` object in the edit view, and there can only be one `academic` in your `User` model.

I would suggest you to build the new academic only if it does not exist already:

```
def edit
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])

  @member.build_academic unless @member.academic
  @member.academic.build_exchange_student unless @member.academic.exchange_student
end
```

PS: you also don't need the `@academic` variable, unless it's not used somewhere else in the edit view.

Comment: thank you very much, worked perfectly! I thought that using the `@academic`, the form would somehow get the object's data, as it does with `@member = Member.find(id)`. Thanks again!